# Copy and replicate changes of file on from parent theme to child theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I’m trying to reverse the styling of header logo title which based on my testing is located inside

```
/wp-content/themes/<theme-name>/inc/partials.php
```

Since the file is under the Parent theme, I needed to replicate this file under the child theme directory

```
/wp-content/themes/<theme-name>-child/inc/partials.php
```

However, I can’t seem to replicate it on my child theme.

For example, in the Parent theme directory, if I reverse the following code block:

```
<h2 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h2>
```

the changes are reflected on the homepage's header part, but if the same changes is applied on the child theme's version of the file, no changes are reflected.

I see that on the Parent theme, the

> partials.php

is included in the

> functions.php

as per the following code snippet:

```
/** Standard Includes */
$includes = array(

    '<other-files>.php',
    '<other-files>.php,

    'partials.php',
    '<other-files>.php',
);

foreach ( $includes as $file ) {
    require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/' . $file );
}
```

Copying this code inside the

> functions.php

on the child theme directory doesn't make it work.

What should I do? What am I missing? TIA

Answer (score 0):

[get_template_directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) function returns the parent theme path. Please check the referenced link.

> In the case a child theme is being used, the absolute path to the
>   parent theme directory will be returned. Use
>   [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) to get the absolute path to the child theme
>   directory.

You can change the `get_template_directory()` function to `get_stylesheet_directory()` function and copy all of those files into your child-theme but it's not recommended since your modification will lost after updating your theme.

I suggest you to contact to your theme author and asking them for a solution to override `/inc/partials.php` file into your child theme.